# Tkinter in IPython Notebook

Tags: tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am running a remote IPython Notebook server. I would like to use a library that has a dependency on Tkinter and this is where my problem lies. Running Tkinter.Tk() gives error message about DISPLAY not being set.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ee/mapclient.py", line 116, in run
    self.parent = Tkinter.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I have no idea what I can do about it in context of the IPython Notebook. Pylab drawings can be displayed without problems. Is there some X forwarding that I could set in Notebook config?

I configured the Notebook according to these instructions: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-python-ipython-notebook/

Comment: you can't use tkinter on a server.